# ASP.NET Creating/Adding Items To Array of Custom Objects

Tags: asp.net

i.e. if I am creating an array as such

```
        Dim webLinesArray() As OrderService.webdirect_WebLinesRow
```

How Can I add items to this array i.e. I want add an item as such

```
Dim webLine As New OrderService.webdirect_WebLinesRow
                webLine.OrderQty = quantity
                webLine.ProductCode = productId
                webLine.LineNumber = 1
                webLinesArray.add or something (webLine)
```

Just that last line I cant figure out how I can add items to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a basic array, you have to resize it and then assing the item to an index in the array, I don't think there is an add for a basic array.

```
Array.Resize(webLinesArray, Newsize)
webLinesArray(index) = Item
```

Comment: Yeah the only problem i see is that it needs to be dynamic size as I wont know the size beforehand

Comment: @StevieB if that's the case, what prevents you from using a List(of T)? That is dynamic and has an "Add" method.

Comment: From the API it looks to me like in the function I am passing this its an array its looking for as an parameter . I.e. <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(IsNullable:=true), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("WebLinesRow", IsNullable:=false)> ByVal WebLines() As webdirect_WebLinesRow

Comment: @StevieB You can still use List(of T) and call the ToArray() method on the List if that's what the API wants.  The ToArray() method will convert the List(of T) to native Array of T.

Answer (score 1):

1) You cannot add an item into an array (they are of a fixed length)
2) You can, however, assign a value to a position in an array (webLinesArray() = foo)

You prob. want to use a List I'd guess, it will allow you to add items dynamically and behaves much like an array does (from the user/programmer standpoint)

Comment: I agree, I almost never use arrays anymore, I always use List(of T)

Answer (score 1):

You have to redim the array:

```
ReDim Preserve webLinesArray(webLinesArray.Length+1)
Now you can store the element at the last position.
```

The Preserve keyword is for preserving the existing values in the array